# Create new file path using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a new file path in regex, in order to move some files. Say I have the path:

```
c:\Users\User\Documents\document.txt
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
c:\Users\User\document.txt
```

Is there an easy way to do this in regex?

Comment: What language are you using and are you sure you want to use regex?

Comment: Is it always the same transformation you want to do, ie remove the last directory in the path? Is it supposed to work only on Windows, or should it work on other OSes as well? The answer depends on all of these. And especially if you have Cygwin, tools exist that will allow you not to use regexes at all.

Comment: I'm using C#. It doesn't have to be regex per se but I though regex might offer a clean solution for this problem. The transformation is the same every time, i.e. I'm using a fixed folder structure. The support for regex doesn't really matter, it's not an application that will be widely distributed :)

Comment: RegEx is pattern matching.  What's the pattern?  Explain it clearly in English and someone will be able to convert it to RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to remove the last folder name from the file path then I think it would be easier to use built-in [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx), [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) instead of regular expressions here:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\Users\User\Documents\document.txt");
if (fileInfo.Directory.Parent != null)
{
    // this will give you "c:\Users\User\document.txt"
    var newPath = Path.Combine(fileInfo.Directory.Parent.FullName, fileInfo.Name);
}
else
{
    // there is no parent folder
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way in Perl regex flavour. It removes last directory in the path:

```
s/[^\\]+\\([^\\]*)$/$1/
```

Explanation:

```
s/.../.../            # Substitute command.
[^\\]+                # Any chars until '\'
\\                    # A back-slash.
([^\\]*)              # Any chars until '\'
$                     # End-of-line (zero-width)
$1                    # Substitute all characters matched in previous expression with expression between parentheses.
```

Comment: At least the first `*` should be a `+`, or even `++` (perl 5.8+) -- but otherwise it just does the job :p

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion. Can I also use this with C#?

Comment: @KeyMs92: Sorry. I'm not in C# but I think regex processing is different. It uses `Regex.Replace` function or something similar. Add `c#` or `.net` tags to the question and for sure many users will give an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try although it is a Java Code

```
String original_path = "c:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\document.txt";
String temp_path =  original_path.substring(0,original_path.lastIndexOf("\\"));
String temp_path_1 = temp_path.substring(0,temp_path.lastIndexOf("\\"));
String temp_path_2 = original_path.substring(original_path.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,original_path.length());

System.out.println(temp_path_1 +"\\" + temp_path_2);
```

You mentioned that transformation is the same every time so, it is not always a good practice to rely on `regexp` for things which can be done using `String manipulations`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not some combination of `pathStr.Split('\\')`, `Take(length - 2)`, and `String.Join`?

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) method. Find what you are looking for, then replace it with nothing (string.empty) here is the C# code:

```
string directory = @"c:\Users\User\Documents\document.txt";
string pattern   = @"(Documents\\)";

Console.WriteLine(  Regex.Replace(directory, pattern, string.Empty ) );

// Outputs 
// c:\Users\User\document.txt
```